# Fire token pawn returned to start by opponent

Tags: sorry

Does a pawn, that has the fire token on it, and is bumped back to **start**  keep the fire token? Or does the fire token go back to center of board?

If you keep the fire token on a return to START, I assume you would take that token directly to **fire** on your next turn before drawing a card.

Answer (score 0):

The rules clearly states that the ring is only moved with a card. So this implies it is not moved when bumped. Which looks like a huge advantage.